# What advantages do CRTs still have over more modern display technologies?

Tags: monitor, crt

Are there any uses for Cathode Ray Tubes in modern world. TVs and Monitors were first, then Oscilloscopes, I am not sure about Radar but are there any applications which will only work with CRTs or which have and edge for CRT use?

Comment: Fastest on-hold I've seen!

Comment: They're useful as a didactic tool for teaching about electron motion and how phosphors can be excited by electrons. They, like other vacuum tubes, are more resistant to damage by EMP than semiconductors, though I don't know if that would be any real advantage--EMPs don't happen often enough to need that. But above all else, they are good at giving things that old-fashioned look!

Comment: @pipe Feels good to put on hold when you cant get one single application specific only to CRT.

Comment: What's opinion based in this question? The obsolescence status of a technology is a market condition which can be verified by statistical data. Of course the interpretation of that data can be somewhat subjective, but this can be said to most EE design decisions! Voting to reopen.

Comment: @FloodGravemind Then go read the [rules](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) before writing a completely off-topic question.

Comment: @pipe Sorry, but there is nothing in the rules that prohibits this kind of questions. The close reason is not justified, imho, as I said in a comment above.

Comment: Answer: light gun/light pen systems. Might be others that require low latency.

Comment: I don't think it should be closed, but it isn't an especially well-written question since the answer wouldn't be very insightful. A better question would be along the lines of "what advantages do CRTs still have over more modern display technologies?" There certainly are plenty.

Comment: Harder to steal, especially the HD flat-front type.

Comment: I recall hearing that there are graphics / photo types who feel the colors are more accurate.  But the question is off topic, because it is not a **specific design question**.  Usage questions are categorically off topic, and "give me an/some examples of" questions are generally off topic in practice as well.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Changes made to fit the rules. Thanks

Comment: And edit can't fix a question that is fundamentally off topic in its very purpose.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Sorry, but I disagree. Questions about the usage of a consumer device are off topic (to avoid questions like `how do I switch on my DVD player/toaster/whatever". A question about where a technology is used or which advantages it has over other technologies is not an usage question, it is a question about the fundamentals of EE design (advantages vs. disadvantages of a technology). We are talking about two very different uses of the word *usage* (pun intended).

Comment: **This *is precisely* a question about *end user* usage** reason for one vs the other.  It would only be on topic if it were about the *design* of a CRT or LCD or other monitor, which it isn't.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Well, if this site were devoted to professionals only, you would be right. From a professional designer POV that is, of course, an end-user question. But this site is also aimed at hobbyists and students, which could conceivably have doubts about these things. From the POV of non-professionals, this is *not* an end-user question (I've never seen common people *using* CRTs - they use equipment *in which CRTs are embedded*).

Comment: @ChrisStratton [continued] This question is on the same line as `what advantages ceramic caps have over PP ones`, which can be trivial for a professional, but not for a student. Until we decide to split the site and create something like programmers.SE, or serverfault.SE (sites explicitly devoted to professionals), we should admit this kind of questions.

Comment: @LorenzoDonati where you are wrong is in ignoring the difference between the fact that selecting capacitors is something *design* engineers do, while selecting **off-the-shelf** monitors is something that end users *system* engineers do.  Again, this is not a question about *designing* a monitor, rather it is about choosing one for imagined applications, and that makes it off topic.  If there were a specific application named this might be on topic on hardware recommendations SE, as it's, it's quite likely off-topic system-wide.

Comment: @Everybody.  Isn't the real (dumb) issue here that a 100 comments have been made discussing whether or not the question was worthy of answering in the first place, rather than directing all those efforts to actually answering it!

Comment: This is off topic because its a subjective question that generates discussion, and its not useful to learning electrical design. From [dont ask](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask): "you are asking an open-ended, hypothetical question: “What if ______ happened?”" or "every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”" There is no right way to answer this question, it should be closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The display is much smoother on an analogue oscilloscope.  You have to pay a lot for a graduated digital display that can produce as perfect a sine wave as :-

[image: sine wave]

If you get something like a used Hameg, they have a simplicity about them that's great for beginners.  They can also demonstrate things that require flying electrons.  J. J. Thomson invented the electron using a rudimentary CRT, and this can still be replicated today in physics classes.

A tangential but beneficial use is converting old oscilloscopes to ersatz digital displays.  The interweb is full of people to have connected DACs and micro controllers to them.  They then make clocks, logic analysers and esoteric art.  I've also seen Quake running on a few.

Comment: The question is about the display technology, not analog oscilloscopes.

Comment: @pipe What's the big green telly like thing on the front of an analogue scope then?  I guess mine's not as good an answer as your's.  Oh wait...

Comment: Ironically, this is an on-topic answer to an off-topic question, because engineering *tools* are explicitly on topic.

Comment: Re: "J. J. Thomson invented the electron": I rather doubt that. :-)

Comment: As @ruakh pointed out, probably you meant *discovered*, instead of *invented*.

Answer (score 7):

CRT displays have several advantages over more modern technologies:

- **Minimal response time**, as incoming pixel data is generally beamed to the screen immediately as received, with virtually no buffering or complex processing like scaling. The phosphors also light up pretty much instantly when desired, unlike liquid crystal pixels.
- **Excellent black level** (and contrast), especially when compared with older LCD technology.
- **Resolution flexibility**. As CRTs don't really have a fixed raster of pixels, they can scan the display at a wide range of vertical and horizontal resolutions without having to resort to scaling.
- Arguably **color rendition**.

Of course, the advantages didn't sufficiently offset the *many* disadvantages that CRTs have:

Higher production cost, larger environmental impact (difficult to recycle, hazardous substances, high power consumption), susceptibility to screen burn-in, sensitivity to magnetic fields, significant warm-up time, tendency to flicker, imposing mass and volume and limited maximum screen size come to mind.

Comment: _"Resolution flexibility. As CRTs don't really have a fixed raster of pixels, ..."_ - Actually, color CRTs typically had a [shadow mask](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_mask) to limit an electron beam to its corresponding phosphor mask. The holes in the shadow mask were effectively subpixels, fixing the resolution of the display. Any other display resolution was effectively scaled like it is in LCDs, except the scaling was done optically rather than electrically.

Comment: I think that you've misunderstood the purpose of a shadow mask.  It's not for quantization of the image into pixels.  It's to cater for e-beam divergence due to multiple e-guns. Read your link again and look at the edges of the big coloured arrow.

Comment: the shadow mask sets an upper limit on the number of pixels possible, but the raster resolution was typically significantly lower than that, and in no way bound to it.  using the term "optically" to describe something that manipulates electrons is brave.

Comment: @PaulUszak Quantization into pixels may not be the purpose of the shadow mask, but it is definitely a side effect. And at display resolutions close to the limit, aliasing is a practical concern.

Comment: @Jasen A 19" CRT with a 0.22mm horizontal dot pitch would have about 1660 dots horizontally, which is right on the edge of being able to properly display 1600x1200 without losing pixels - never mind without aliasing. Anyway, my point was that the resolution flexibility argument of (color) CRTs is a bit more complicated than it first appears ;)

Comment: @marcelm I just wanted to keep the answer simple and practical, without dwelling into details. It's true that color CRTs have an upper bound for the resolution due to the shadow mask/aperture grille, but for practical purposes this can be ignored as CRTs are never operated at resolutions close to said limits. You also resorted to oversimplification, as shadow mask isn't the only color CRT tech around: aperture grille CRTs have no vertical "subpixels" at all (only a horizontal pitch).

Comment: What about the bright-to-dark response time? I say response time is not a benefit of CRTs.

Comment: response time depends on the phosphor speed and retrace rate. 70hz retrace was a common figure for ordinary SVGA displays response time 0 to 14ms about 14 times faster than typical human reaction times.  other displays may use slower of faster phosphors,  eg. radar displays.  and medical CROs used much slower phosphor.